# prometheus-node_exporter grafana: How to display the status of all nodes in the cluster? Including survivors and hangers

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

I am using grafana to display the cluster data monitored by node_exporter of prometheus.
I want to summarize all the nodes. If they survive, the IP and CPU usage will be displayed (IP needs to remove the port number); if they hang, the IP will be displayed, and the color is gray;Now you can see the CPU usage of the surviving nodes;[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1leR.png)
The query is this :

```
label_replace((1 - avg(irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{job=~"$job",mode="idle"}[5m])) by(instance)) * 100,"hostip","$1","instance","(.*):9100")
```

Now I want to show the nodes with up==0 (hang up), and show them in gray. What should I do?
I thought of using the or operator ,as shown: `( label_replace((1 - avg(irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{job=~"$job",mode="idle"}[5m])) by(instance)) * 100,"hostip","$1","instance","(.*):9100") ) or on(instance) up{job=~"node-exporter"}`

But the result is like this：[The red circle is the node that is down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1IAl.png).
The red circle is the node that is down. I want the nodes that are down (up==0) to be gray, but the CPU usage is 0 and the nodes that are alive are green. The same value but not the same metric, how to distinguish the two?
I would like to ask you, thank you very much!